# Angular2: pass boolean to @Input

Tags: angular

I'm writing a reusable component in angular2. In the parent component, I can set the value of the @Input in the child by including it in the template like this:

```
 <child-component #logoutModal [button1Text]="'Do Something Groovy'" 
  [showbutton1]="false"></child-component'
```

The text is interpolated into the child using `{{ button1Text }}`, as expected. However, for the boolean above, the value isn't passed into the template. If I do `{{showButton1}}` in the child component's template, it displays `true`, which is the default value set in the child's class using the `@Input` decorator.

EDIT: here's how I set the default values in the child component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // default values
  @Input() public showButton1: boolean = true;
  @Input() public button1Text: string = 'OK';
  //..
```

How do I override/set this boolean value from the parent component? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show that part of your component?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It should be

```
[showButton1]
```

instead of

```
[showbutton1]
```

(uppercase `B` - Angular2 templates are case sensitive)

Comment: DOH! Face-palm. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out why my boolean input wasn't respecting the booleaness of the input (I was missing the square brackets). Thanks for the simple example.